# Index vs Auto Increment ID set as PK

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In MySQL, what is the difference between Index and an *ID* set to `AUTO_INCREMENT` and as Primary Key?

Will this also increase the speed to searching the database? Or is the `AUTO_INCREMENT` *ID* just for the purpose of the of the user and the computer doesn't consider it while searching the database? Reading about `INDEX` on w3schools.com I came across this line:

> Indexes are used to retrieve data from the database very fast. The
>   users cannot see the indexes, they are just used to speed up
>   searches/queries.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, the primary key creates an index on the key . . . but the original data pages are the leafs of the index.  This may be a little convoluted, but the effect is that the data is actually sorted on the data pages.

A regular index is implemented as a b-tree (note:  the "b" standards for "balanced" rather than "binary", contrary to what many people believe).  The leafs are stored separately from the original data.

`auto_increment` is a property of one column of a table, where the value is set to a new value on each insert and the new value is larger than the previous value.  The increment is usually 1, but that is not guaranteed.  `auto_increment` does not directly relate to indexing, but is almost always associated with the primary key of the table.

So, in both cases, you have an index.  The primary key index is slightly smaller because storage is combined with the data pages themselves.  On the other hand, the data needs to be in order on the disk, which can complicate inserts and updates.  On the other hand, auto-increment guarantees that all new rows go at the end of the data.  On the other hand, I've run out of hands.

Answer (score 1):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` is an integer sequence generator and nothing else. It has no inherent relation to indexes of any kind, and only exists to generate unique sequential numbers. It is frequently used to generate integer [surrogate keys](https://it.toolbox.com/question/the-difference-between-a-primary-key-and-a-surrogate-key-011407) which are frequently used as primary keys.

You don't have to use either `AUTO_INCREMENT` or integer IDs as an index so long as you have one or more fields that you can use to uniquely identify a row.

In fact, in terms of scalability, sequence generators like `AUTO_INCREMENT` are counter-productive as you can only ever have a single instance of a sequence generator, limiting the number of 'master/write' servers and/or bottlenecking insert performance to that of the node running the generator.

Answer (score 0):

When you index a column, you make a binary tree (or possibly another data structure) to speed up the search process.

ID or primary key by default is indexed.

Auto_Increment means you want MySQL to automatically set a value to the column whenever a new row gets inserted. The value will be set incrementally.